# How to get a list of all documents in a Firebase Cloud Firestore database using the API?

Tags: rest, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to query my Cloud Firestore database periodically for maintenance. I'm new to REST and I've spent way too long trying to solve this myself, so I figured I could use some advice.

My Firestore is set up like so:

`users > {uid} > uploaded-files > {file-hash}`

`{file-hash}` is a document that contains several fields such as `filename`, `source`, and `size`

All I'm trying to do is get a list of every single `filename` from every single `uploaded-file`, including from multiple `{uid}`'s.

---

I've managed to send a successful request and get a single `filename` using the `firestore.projects.databases.documents.get` method using the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/), but I can't seem to get any other methods to work, namely `firestore.projects.databases.documents.list`

This is the successful request using `firestore.projects.databases.documents.get`:

```
GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{project-id}/databases/(default)/documents/users/7eGfdgGfaG0HSXdfmxMN2/uploaded-files/WGtcJBX9fdGdhdtjB?mask.fieldPaths=filename&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Part of my issue is that I can't figure out how to get requests to work without hard-linking document names - in other words, I don't know how to to replace `{uid}`, or any other collection, with a wild-card so that the request returns documents from *all* uid's.

---

Really any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Use the Cloud Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) documentation has instructions on getting started. The [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/) documentation shows how to fetch documents.

In your case you would need to [list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/list) the user-uid documents then go after the `uploaded-files` for each one, or iterate over the results of the `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have implemented the solution for this:

```
const fs = require('firebase-admin');
const app = require('express')();
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey_DEV.json');

fs.initializeApp({
    credential: fs.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = fs.firestore();

    Get the all tables inside the projects
    app.get("/collectionlists", async (req, res, next) => {
        const tables = [];
        db.listCollections()
            .then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach(snaps => {
                    tables.push(snaps["_queryOptions"].collectionId);
                    console.log(snaps["_queryOptions"].collectionId); // LIST OF ALL COLLECTIONS
                });
                res.send(tables);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });
```

The above API will give you a list of all collections.
Thank you